# Немного не ясен смысл JNDI

Tags: java, api

Понятно для чего его использовать, чтобы вносить в контекст объекты и привязывать к ним определенный name, а потом когда они понадобятся - доставать их из контекста по заданному имени. Но вот непонятны разные реализации JNDI, в чем их смысл? Там уже есть объекты с определенными именами? и вообще есть подобное в JNDI(какие-то зарезервированные объекты с определенными именами)

Comment: Понятно для чего использовать автомобили - чтобы ездить и возить что-то, но вот непонятны разные марки и модели. В чём их смысл?

Comment: никогда этого не понимал. К чему вы это написали?

Comment: К тому, что JNDI - это просто стандартизированный API, у которого должны быть реализации. Каждый может сделать свою реализацию JNDI. Она может вообще не отличаться от других реализаций или может иметь какие-то особенности.Поэтому ваш вопрос похож на "Почему в мире есть разные операционные системы/языки программирования/СУБД/прочее?"

Comment: Так в JNDI есть зарезервированные объекты с определенными именами?

Comment: Могут быть.Но, если мне не изменяет память, [спецификация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jndi/index.html) ничего подобного не требует.

Comment: Т.е. это как бы построитель пути к чему либо, а потом по этому пути можно достать что-нибудь?  Например, путь в файловой системе к какой-либо директории и после выводим(например методом list()) те файлы/директории, которые лежат  по указанному пути, я правильно понял?

Comment: Это иерархический каталог любой информации. Программа может искать в нём параметры подключения к БД, другие программы, работающие на том же сервере, сервис проверки подлинности учётных записей и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Получается, главное задать корень каталога, откуда будет начинаться поиск чего либо. Вот после этой статьи стало более понятно: http://forum.vingrad.ru/articles/topic-157996.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Смысл JNDI в том, что это **внешняя конфигурация**. К примеру, у тебя есть приложение, которое использует соединение с БД. Если требуется, чтобы приложение стояло на разных площадках (тестовая, девелоперская, продуктовая и т.д.), то, решая проблему в лоб, тебе потребуется создать для каждой площадки по отдельному приложению с зашитой внутрь конфигурацией.

Естественно, что портируемость у такого способа будет нулевая. Тут на помощь приходит **JNDI**. Твоя среда, к примеру сервер tomcat, поставляет этот объект-соединение с БД `javax.sql.DataSource` как внешнюю конфигурацию. И параметры этого соединения с БД (хост, пользователь и т.д.) настраиваются уже со стороны среды.

Т.е. у тебя получается одно **портируемое** приложение, которое можно устанавливать на разные площадки.